# Proof: Complex number convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

My complex analysis textbook says the following:

> ... the reader can check that the sequence $\{ z_n \}$ converges to $w$ if and only if the sequence of real and imaginary parts of $z_n$ converge to the real and imaginary parts of $w$, respectively.

Since we need to prove logical equivalence, we will need two proofs (one for either direction).

**Proof 1:**

I begin by assuming that the sequence $\{ z_n \}$ converges to $w$, and my aim is to show that the sequence of real and imaginary parts of $z_n$ converge to the real and imaginary parts of $w$, respectively.

$$| z_n - w | \ge || z_n | - | w || \ge | \mathcal{R} \{ z_n \} - \mathcal{R} \{ w \} |$$

(Since $|\mathcal{R} \{ z \}| \le |z|$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$.)

Therefore, we have that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } || z_n | - | w || \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} | \mathcal{R} \{ z_n \} - \mathcal{R} \{ w \} |  $$

And since we assumed that the sequence $\{ z_n \}$ converges to $w$ (that is, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = w$), we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} | \mathcal{R} \{ z_n \} - \mathcal{R} \{ w \} |$ converges to $0$, since $\lim_{n \to \infty } || z_n | - | w ||$ converges to $0$.

And so we have shown that the real parts of $z_n$ converge to the real parts of $w$.

The proof of convergence for the imaginary parts is analogous.

**Proof 2:**

I begin by assuming that the real and imaginary parts of $z_n$ converge to the real and imaginary parts of $w$.

$$\begin{align} | z_n - w | &= | (x_n + iy_n) - (x + iy)| \\ &= | (x_n - x) + i(y_n - y)| \\ &= \sqrt{ (x_n - x)^2 + (y_n - y)^2 } \end{align}$$

We assumed that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = y$.

$$\begin{align} \therefore \lim_{n \to \infty} | z_n - w | &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{ (x_n - x)^2 + (y_n - y)^2 } \\ &= \sqrt{ (x - x)^2 + (y - y)^2 } \\ &= 0\end{align}$$

And so we have shown that the sequence $\{ z_n \}$ converges to $w$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please advise me as to the correctness of my proof.

Comment: First displayed formula: You have a limit on the RHS which is hypothesised to be zero. The middle term may be nonzero. The second inequality sign is the wrong way round.

Comment: The sequence also converges if it is cauchy sequence

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. Inequality sign fixed. What else is wrong with the first proof?

Comment: I recommend using  the inequality $|(x_n+iy_n)-(x+y)| \leq  |x_n-x|+|y_n-y|$ instead of the one you used.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But the second proof seems to be correct anyway. I think it’s the first proof that’s incorrect?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I changed the first proof. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your forward direction:

Suppose $z_1=1$ and $w=-1$, then $$||z_1|-|w||=0$$

but 
$$|\mathcal{R}\{z_1\}-\mathcal{R}\{w\}|=2$$

Hence $||z_1|-|w|| \ge |\mathcal{R}\{z_1\}-\mathcal{R}\{w\}|$ is not true.

To prove $$|z_n-w|\ge |\mathcal{R}\{z_n\}-\mathcal{R}\{w\}|$$

We have

$$|z_n-w| \ge |\mathcal{R}\{z_n-w\}|=|\mathcal{R}\{z_n\}-\mathcal{R}\{w\}|$$

where the first inequality is due to $|\mathcal{R}\{z\}|\le |z|$.

Now, we can take limit on both sides,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|z_n-w| \ge \lim_{n \to \infty}|\mathcal{R}\{z_n\}-\mathcal{R}\{w\}|$$

and conclude that the real part converges.

For the reverse direction:

You might like to define $x_n$, $y_n$, $x$, and $y$ explicitly and I think you meant to say

$$| (x_n + iy_n) - (x + iy)| = | (x_n - x) \color{blue}+ i(y_n - y)| $$

even though what you wrote is still correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything. You're absolutely correct. I have one question that I am unsure about: Is $\mathcal{R}$ actually a linear operator? Because that's what it's treated as, it seems. I haven't read anything about it being an operator, but I see that people treat it like one, so I'm curious what it is? Thanks again!

Comment: We need a field when we discuss linear operator. If the field is the real number then yes. We can check that $\mathcal{R}(x+y) = \mathcal{R}(x)+\mathcal{R}(y)$ and  $\mathcal{R}(cx)= c\mathcal{R}(x)$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But in the case of $|\mathcal{R}\{z_n-w\}|=|\mathcal{R}\{z_n\}-\mathcal{R}\{w\}|$, wouldn't the field be the complex numbers ($\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: I mean the $c$ in the multiplication, it has to be real. For additions, we just deal with the vector field, which is the complex number.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. It's been a while since I thought about fields.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps mean $\ge$ instead of $\le$ in the first proof? It is perhaps best to explain why your inequality is true; it is not immediately obvious. Your second proof looks fine.

Perhaps a tip to make the equations simpler; you could simply translate the entire complex plane to send $w$ to $0$, noting that convergence under either definition is unaffected. You would then be able to avoid the use of the triangle inequality and multiple variables.

Comment: I changed the first proof. What do you think?